# Select row meeting condition and all subsequent rows by group

Tags: r

Let's assume I have a data frame consisting of a categorical variable and a numerical one.

```
df <- data.frame(group=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),days=floor(runif(10, min=0, max=101)))

df
    group days
1      1   54
2      1   61
3      1   31
4      1   52
5      1   21
6      2   22
7      2   18
8      2   50
9      2   46
10     2   35
```

I would like to select the row corresponding to the maximum number of days by group as well as all the following/subsequent group rows. For the example above, my subset df2 should look as follows:

```
df2
    group days
2      1   61
3      1   31
4      1   52
5      1   21
8      2   50
9      2   46
10     2   35
```

Please note that the groups could have different lengths.

Comment: use `set.seed(123L)` at the top of your post to make the example reproducible.

Answer (score 3):

For a base R solution, aggregate days by group using a function that keeps the elements with index greater than or equal to the maximum, and then reshape as a long data.frame

```
df0 = aggregate(days ~ group, df, function(x) x[seq_along(x) >= which.max(x)])
data.frame(group=rep(df0$group, lengths(df0$days)),          
           days=unlist(df0$days, use.names=FALSE)))
```

leading to

```
   group days
1     1   84
2     1   31
3     1   65
4     1   23
5     2   94
6     2   69
7     2   45
```

Comment: Or use `ave` - `df[with(df, ave(days,group,FUN=function(x) cumsum(x==max(x)))>=1),]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `which.max` to find out the index of the maximum of the `days` and then use `slice` from `dplyr` to select all the rows after that, where `n()` gives the number of rows in each group:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(group) %>% slice(which.max(days):n())

#Source: local data frame [7 x 2]
#Groups: group [2]

#  group  days
#  <int> <int>
#1     1    61
#2     1    31
#3     1    52
#4     1    21
#5     2    50
#6     2    46
#7     2    35
```

`data.table` syntax would be similar, `.N` is similar to `n()` in `dplyr` and gives the number of rows in each group:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[which.max(days):.N], group]

#   group days
#1:     1   61
#2:     1   31
#3:     1   52
#4:     1   21
#5:     2   50
#6:     2   46
#7:     2   35
```

Comment: what if the variable days has missing values within all groups? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to keep all the `NA`s, `which.max` can deal with `NA` values, for example. `which.max(c(3,4,5,NA,5, 7, 4))` gives 6 which is the index of 7. If you don't want to keep them, add `na.omit()` to the end of the pipeline should be fine. Something like: `df %>% group_by(group) %>% slice(which.max(days):n()) %>% na.omit()`

Comment: I get the following error for a different dataset:    Error: argument of length 0.

Comment: You probably have some groups that have all `NA` for the days variable. Try to filter that group first. `df %>% group_by(group) %>% filter(!all(is.na(days))) %>% slice(which.max(days):n()) %>% na.omit()`

Comment: @Psidom the problem is your slice expression, e.g., `which.max(NA):1` and it would be better to fix that common problem than to work around it with a filter.

Comment: I think that's the same as what I am saying. `which.max(NA)` happens only when all the days in a group are NAs. no?

Comment: Yes, we agree on the diagnosis; I'm suggesting that the solution is to use a robust slice function, rather than an ad hoc filter.

Comment: Works great - very neat. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinMorgan I think a more robust way probably be the method you are using. `df %>% group_by(group) %>% slice(which(seq_along(days) >= which.max(days)))`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use a faster option with `data.table` where we find the row index (`.I`) and then subset the rows based on that.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[ , .I[which.max(days):.N], by = group]$V1]
#   group days
#1:     1   61
#2:     1   31
#3:     1   52
#4:     1   21
#5:     2   50
#6:     2   46
#7:     2   35
```